# Find original values that have been adjusted by a matrix from adjusted values

Tags: matrices

I have a Javascript methods which adjusts values in an array by applying a matrix to them and adding the results. In flow cytometry, this is called a "spillover".

The code is:

```
let adjustSpillover = function (origValues) {
    let matrix = [
        [
            1.0015153082093076,
            -0.1782672418018901,
            -0.001051329309471067
        ],
        [
            -0.008512873314297068,
            1.0015152703439572,
            -0.00021130192602001406
        ],
        [
            -0.00003477265361437083,
            0.000006189446131432386,
            1.000000036502198
        ]
    ];


    var adjusted = [];
  
  for (var x = 0; x < origValues.length; x++) {
    adjusted[x] = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < origValues.length; i++) {
      if (matrix[i][x] != 0) {
        var orig = origValues[i];

        let after = orig * matrix[i][x];

        adjusted[x] = Math.round(adjusted[x] + after);
        console.log("adjusted[x] is ",adjusted[x]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(">>> adjusted is ",adjusted);
  return adjusted;
}

let adjusted1 = adjustSpillover([
    8945,
    7134,
    148
]);



console.log("adjusted is ", adjusted);
```

And it outputs `[8898, 5550, 137]`

As equations it looks like:

```
adjusted = (orig0 * matrix[0][0]) + (orig1 * matrix[1][0]) + (orig2 * matrix[2][0]) // 8898

adjusted2 = (orig0 * matrix[0][1]) + (orig1 * matrix[1][1]) + (orig2 * matrix[2][1]) // 5550

adjusted3 = (orig0 * matrix[0][2]) + (orig1 * matrix[1][2]) + (orig2 * matrix[2][2]) // 137
```

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to calculate the reversal of this method i.e. a method that takes the adjusted array, and applies the matrix to find the original array. My attempt:

```
let calculateOriginalValues = function (adjustedValues) {
    let matrix = [        [            1/1.0015153082093076,            -1/-0.1782672418018901,            -1/-0.001051329309471067        ],
        [            -1/-0.008512873314297068,            1/1.0015152703439572,            -1/-0.00021130192602001406        ],
        [            -1/-0.00003477265361437083,            -1/0.000006189446131432386,            1/1.000000036502198        ]
    ];

    let originalValues = [];

    for (let x = 0; x < adjustedValues.length; x++) {
        originalValues[x] = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < adjustedValues.length; i++) {
            let adj = adjustedValues[i];

            let orig = adj * matrix[x][i];

            originalValues[x] = Math.round(originalValues[x] + orig);
        }
    }

    return originalValues;
}

let originalValues = calculateOriginalValues([8898, 5550, 137]);
console.log("originalValues is", originalValues);
```

However this gives the result [170329, 1699144, -640796790]. I want the output [8945, 7134, 148].

Is what Im trying to do even possible? For memory reasons I cannot store the original array.

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/mark-kelly-the-looper/pen/GRBeLLX

My code is an implementation of flow cytometry here: http://www.bioinformin.net/cytometry/compensation.php

I want to find the original values as users can edit the matrix. So I need to use the original matrix to find the original values from the adjusted values.

Comment: I _think_ what you are trying to do is simply to apply the inverse of a matrix. You don't find that inverse by inverting the individual elements. Look up "invert a matrix" and you'll find out how. I'm sure there's a javascript implementation out there. Or, since the matrix is hard coded, just ask some on line tool to invert it for you and paste the answer into your code.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think its more complex than that. By the way this is what Im doing, the Javascript code I wrote is an implementation of this http://www.bioinformin.net/cytometry/compensation.php

Comment: Reading your link I think my comment is right. You are doing just what I thought. In that link the line "Matrix inversion of $SM$ ... gives $CM$" is the important step. The $CM$ matrix in your calculateOriginalValues function is wrong. Find the right one at https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/matrix-inverse-calculator

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you, you are correct, multiplying the result by the inverse got me the originals

Comment: You're welcome. I think you can delete the question since it's not of general interest and shouldn't stay on the unanswered queue. Either that or post an answer yourself and accept it.